# Handle one to many relations in Linq using Entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4.1

I have table called `Direccion` other called `Cliente` each one defined like this

```
public class Direccion
{   
    public short IdDireccion { get; set; }
    public short IdCliente { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Cliente> Cliente { get; set; }
}

public class Cliente
{
    public short IdCliente { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
}
```

Now what I want to accomplish is a query with this output by generating an anonymous type

```
id            <----could be idCliente or idDireccion
Descripcion   <----could be the description of cliente or Direccion
idFK          <---- the id of direccion related with cliente
```

But I start to have trouble when I navigate from `Direccion` to `Cliente` because the relation gives me the collection and I don't know how to make the expression to handle the collection to the type that I'm expecting which is `Cliente`

This is my failed attempt:

```
var x= (from d in Direccion
where d.Activo == true select d.Cliente).Select( x => new { x.IdCliente })

var x = (from d in db.Direccion
                     where d.Activo == true
                     select d).AsQueryable().Select(xx => new { d.IdCliente });
```

Comment: Cliente is a collection, so you may have many of them.  What output do you expect to get when a Direccion has multiple Clientes?

Comment: I want to select the id and the desciption

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Simply access your list of clients?

Comment: to get a simple access, with the first query it's enough

Comment: Jorge, what results do you expect if there are two?  Two different IDs and descriptions?

Comment: Exactly.... but in the same fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the SelectMany method:

```
var x = from d in db.Direccion
        where d.Activo == true
        from c in d.Cliente
        select new 
        { c.IdCliente,
          c.Descripcion };
```